# A satellite's view of the Earth: relating the rates of change of angle and height

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

When satellites observe the Earth, they can scan only part of the Earth's surface. Some satellites have sensors that can measure the angle θ shown in the figure. Let h represent the satellite's distance from the Earth's surface and let r represent Earth's radius.

[image]

(a) Show that h = r(csc(θ) − 1).

(b) Find the rate at which h is changing with respect to θ when θ = 20°. (Assume r = 3960 miles. Round to the nearest mile/degree.)
  miles/degree

Thanks

Comment: "can measure the angle θ shown in the figure" - what figure? Also, you should say what you have attempted so far, and where you are stuck

Comment: There I posted the figure and I have basically not attempted nothing so far because the teacher has not gave us a problem like this. I tried figuring where to start, but didn't know where. Just help me on what would be the first step.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius at that point.  That gives you a right triangle from the center of the earth to the tangent point to the satellite.

Answer (score 0):

In the diagram, you have a right-angled triangle. You have one angle given as $\theta$, and you have 2 sides given - one from the satellite to the centre of the Earth, which has length $h+r$, and another side from the centre of the Earth to the point where the right angle is, which has length $r$.

Can you come up with a trigonometric relationship between these 3 pieces of information you have?

Comment: You mean like opposite over hypotenuse?

Comment: @user488886 yes, $\sin(\text{angle})=\frac{\text{Opposite}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}$. Use this and rearrange to try and get the answer they ask for in part (a).

Comment: and then for b? I just plug in r and theta?

Comment: If you simply plug in the values, then this will give you the value of $h$. But it asks for rate of change of $h$, not what its value is. Do you remember how you find rate of change of something?

Comment: She only gave us one example of a rate of change problem. Something about making a position function.

Comment: @user488886 Have you learned about derivatives? $\frac{dh}{d\theta}$ gives the rate of change of $h$ with respect to $\theta$. You need to calculate this first, **then** substitute in the values of r and $\theta$

Comment: Yes, we learned derivatives like a week ago and okay.

Comment: So -3960/(3960+h)^2 then h=-2.52E-4?

Comment: I got -1939 for the rate of change.    dh/dtheta= -rcsc(θ)cot(θ) = -3960(1/sin(20))(cos20/sin20) = -1939

Comment: Got it thanks very much!

Comment: No problem :)${}$

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward trigonometry and a little Calculus.  $sin(\theta)= \frac{r}{r+ h}$.  Differentiating both sides with respect to h, $cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dh}= -\frac{r}{(r+ h)^2}$

Comment: This is for part A right?